# Evaluating An Integral $\int \frac{1 - \sin x}{x - \cos x} dx$

Tags: calculus

I was evaluating the integral $\int \frac{1 - \sin x}{x - \cos x} dx$ as an exercise.

My work:

Let $$\sin x = \frac{2z}{1+z^2}$$
$$\cos x = \frac{1-z^2}{1+z^2}$$
$$dx = \frac{2dz}{1 + z^2}$$
$$x = ln (1+z^2)$$

I got the expression of $x$ by integrating $dx$

Then substituting these expressions to $\int \frac{1 - \sin x}{x - \cos x} dx$, 
it becomes:

$$\int \frac{\left(1-\frac{2z}{1+z^2}\right) \left(\frac{2z}{1+z^2}\right)} {ln(1+z^2)+ \frac{1-z^2}{1+z^2}}$$

$$\int \frac{\frac{2+4z+4z^2+4z^3+2z^2}{(1+z^2)^3}}{\frac{(1+z^2) ln (1+z^2) + (1 - z^2)}{1 + z^2}}$$

At this point, I'm stuck.How would I proceed?

Comment: @platty The really obvious thing to try has the wrong sign in the numerator.

Comment: It may be that there is a typo in your problem statement, and that specifically the numerator is supposed to be $1+\sin(x)$. If not, Wolfram Alpha finds no result in terms of elementary functions. If it is supposed to be $1+\sin(x)$, then the problem is quite easy, simply substitute $u=x-\cos(x)$.

Comment: @platty oh no.....you're right.....XD

Comment: @Ian  yes...you're right.....XD